# Why do I get up to 99% error in Jmeter FTP request (Linux vsftpd) at over 50 users?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, jmeter, ftp, vsftpd

we are currently working on a school project in which we are comparing Windows and Linux server roles. We decided to use Jmeter for performance testing but we ran into some weird results for FTP requests.
The tests were performed as 20 minutes of infinitely looping tests that incrementally increased users (threads). Hardware is identical, and the Jmeter plans are duplicates except for changed IP-addresses.

First we tested 10 users for 20 minutes, then 20 users for 20 minutes -> 50 users -> finally 100 users. The requests contain a get-retrieval for a 1 MB dummy-file.
Windows FTP went through all the tests with 0.0% error but the Linux FTP started running into errors at around 40-50 users. 50 users had 77% error, and 100 users had 99% error.

Is the Linux FTP-software not designed for this many continuous users or are we missing some configurations? Thanks for any input :)

[Linux FTP 20 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vO6u.png)

[Linux FTP 50 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgfOs.png)

[Linux FTP 100 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfW2S.png)

[Windows FTP 100 users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wg88G.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [How do I limit the number of simultaneous vsftpd connections from the same IP address](https://access.redhat.com/articles/6434)

> The default value for maximum number of simultaneous vsftpd connections coming from the same source is 50

You need to set the following directives in `vsftpd.conf`:

- `max_per_ip=0` - remove limit of connections from single IP address
- `max_clients=1000` - set maximum number of connections to 1000

Additional information:

- [VSFTPD limit the number of simultaneous vsftpd connections for a single IP address](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-limit-number-of-simultaneous-vsftpd-connections/)
- [VSFTPD - limiting connections](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Very_Secure_FTP_Daemon#Limiting_connections)
- [Load Testing FTP and SFTP Servers Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-ftp-and-sftp-servers-using-jmeter/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! We changed it as you suggested and now the test with 50 users had 1,4% error. The test with 100 users seems to still have a large portion of errors (75%) but it's still an improvement from 99% errors :P Do you think there could be something else which is causing these errors that we could configure? Again, thanks a bunch!